# Replace image names with actual images from folder?

Tags: image, ubuntu, replace, libreoffice

I basically have a document with all image names listed in it.I also have the images with the same names in a separate folder. 
Is there any method/software/script I can follow (Win/Ubuntu) so that I can replace the image text in the document with the actual image from the folder?
Since the image has to replaced in the document, I'm thinking this can only be done in a word/PDF processing software ?
Microsoft office or Libre Office ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are programming ways to create/modify Microsoft Word document, which will definitely resolve your problem. for example in C# language: [Here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj7zaDbmILNAhUBWhQKHdlBAzUQFggqMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dotnetperls.com%2Fword&usg=AFQjCNEQguuOHkhsPZ8-q5Ili_G6qPvaqQ&sig2=wP4NTr_DuB-GnAHPJSVU2g&bvm=bv.123325700,d.bGg)

Also there is VBScripts for Microsoft which is easier to learn and are executed inside the software. One example to add an image: [Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692911.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thanks! The C# really went over my head, but the other link was very helpful. I know how to insert an image now, and I know how to search using VB too. Jusy have to figure out how to capture the exact word, since the search term will be a regex (image00.*-00.*) of the sort, and then replace it with the image having the same name. Again, that would be easy if I can get the instance that matches the regex.

Answer (score 0):

For LibreOffice, [Andrew Pitonyak's macro document](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=andrew%20macro) has exactly what you're asking for.  Listing 5.30 finds names of images using a regular expression and then inserts the images into the document.